# Rock Paper Scissors Difficulty Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Im trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game where you choose 1,2 or 3 for rock then displays what you've chosen and what the computer has chosen. I then need to keep track of score for wins and at the end of every round ask the user if they want to play again.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class Rock5
     {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Plays the Rock-Paper-Scissors game with the user.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
  final int OPTIONS = 3;
  final int ROCK = 1, PAPER = 2, SCISSORS = 3;
  final int COMPUTER = 1, PLAYER = 2, TIE = 3;

  int computer, player, winner = 0;
  int wins = 0, losses = 0, ties = 0;
  String again;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  do
  {
     computer = (int) (Math.random() * OPTIONS) + 1;

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print ("Enter your choice - 1 for Rock, 2 for " +
                          "Paper, and 3 for Scissors: ");
     player = in.nextInt();

     System.out.print ("My choice was ");

     // Determine the winner
     switch (computer)
     {
        case ROCK:
           System.out.println ("Rock.");
           if (player == SCISSORS)
              winner = COMPUTER;
           else
              if (player == PAPER)
                 winner = PLAYER;
              else
                 winner = TIE;
           break;

        case PAPER:
           System.out.println ("Paper.");
           if (player == ROCK)
              winner = COMPUTER;
           else
              if (player == SCISSORS)
                 winner = PLAYER;
              else
                 winner = TIE;
           break;

        case SCISSORS:
           System.out.println ("Scissors.");
           if (player == PAPER)
              winner = COMPUTER;
           else
              if (player == ROCK)
                 winner = PLAYER;
              else
                 winner = TIE;
     }

     // Print results and increment appropriate counter
     if (winner == COMPUTER)
     {
        System.out.println ("I win!");
        losses++;
     }
     else
        if (winner == PLAYER)
        {
           System.out.println ("You win!");
           wins++;
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println ("We tied!");
           ties++;
        }

     System.out.println();
     System.out.print ("Play again (y/n)?: ");
     again = in.nextLine();
  }
  while (again.equalsIgnoreCase ("y"));

  // Print final results
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println ("You won " + wins + " times.");
  System.out.println ("You lost " + losses + " times.");
  System.out.println ("We tied " + ties + " times.");
```

}
}

Comment: And I need a new bike.  Now what is your question?

Comment: Also, Java and Javascript are not the same thing.  They are as similar as Car and Carpet.

Comment: why isnt the program asking the user if they want to play again?

Comment: It's inside an else statement.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
player = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
```

Instead of

```
player = in.nextInt();
```

and it'll work, because if not, the  number you enter goes into `player`, and the \n characater goes into `again = in.nextLine()` and because it's different of `y` it stops.